# IP Addressing Plan

Tags: networking, tcp, ip, ip-address, computer-science

Devise an IP addressing plan for the city- wide network (4 sites), including 4
subnets for the 4 sites. Remember that the 4,000 hosts are divided equally
across the 4 sites.
You are to request a classless IP address Block from the following base IP
address: 142.212.128.0/17
You need to produce a complete design of the addressing scheme supported by
proofs.
In order to present your answer you will need to:
a. Based on the total number of addresses required, state the classless IP address
block that should be assigned to the company including the mask.
b. The assigned IP address block should be equally divided across the
company’s 4 sites to create separate routing domains, i.e. each site should have
its own IP subnet.
Divide the assigned block equally across the 4 sites and provide the following
for each site:
1. base IP address
2. subnet mask
3. the block’s routable first and last addresses

This is the question, I am just wondering since there is only 4000 required IP Addresses why is there a need to /17 instead of /20 ? Quite confused here..

Answer (score 0):

You have a supply of addresses that is a /17 (~32 000 addresses), out of which you need to request CIDR blocks to support whatever IP addressing scheme you devise. The question indicates that the 4 COIDR blocks should be able to form a larger CIDR block.